# QtCreator/QMake - How to add .qmlproject (QtQuick2 UI app) into subdirs .pro project?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake, qtquick2

I have folders:

```
dev_root
  all.pro
  app
    app.pro
  ext
    ext.pro
  ui
    ui.qmlproject
```

I have .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    ext \
    ui

ext.subdir         = ext
app.depends        = ext
ui.depends           = ext
```

But qmake reports an error:

```
Could not find .pro file for sub dir 'ui'
```

How can I add .qmlproject into subdirs .pro project?

Answer (score 0):

A `Qt Quick-UI` application is just a simple way to run QML files with QML Scene. It has nothing to do with C++ and QMake. Thus is cannot be a subproject of a QMake subdirs-project.